# Wondering if a USB dongle for gaming controller could have malware installed

Tags: malware, hardware, usb, keyloggers, gaming

I purchased a usb gaming controller used. It has a usb dongle that plugs into the PC and a I assume its bluetooth.

Is it possible for the USB dongle to contain a keylogger that starts up when I plug it in?

Im just curious if someone could have installed a keylogger on it? Ive tried reading up and some say yes it is possible, but others say that dongles are specialized hardware and don't have storage on them.

Thanks,

Comment: after some research i found that it is possible to turn any usb into a Hacking Device. and here's some reading material for you.
https://hackmag.com/security/rubber-ducky/

Comment: Could i plug it into my linux laptop and inspect it? Or would hackers hide the scripts that autorun

Comment: you could plug it and check the outgoing connections and look for irregular connections by using `netstat` and `systemctl`, also check out this question; https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/56453/how-can-i-monitor-all-outgoing-requests-connections-from-my-machine

Comment: But in general @Maverick S. the usb bluetooth adapter is read-only? It would have to have been tampered at the hardware level?

Comment: Any USB device could host malware or keyloggers

Comment: "dongles are specialized hardware and don't have storage on them" -- unless someone adds storage or replaces the hardware